# no matching member function for call to 'insert'

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following method declaration on a `basic_buffer` class:

```
const_iterator insert(const_iterator position, typename argument<value_type>::type val)
```

Notice the type of the second argument. I often use this `argument` traits that basically decides whether the argument should be passed by copy or by reference when receiving template arguments. In this case, `value_type` is a `typedef` of the template argument `T`. For instance, fundamental types should be passed by copy instead of const reference. Here's the implementation:

```
template <typename T> struct argument
{
    typedef std::conditional<std::is_fundamental<T>::value || std::is_pointer<T>::value, const T, const T &> type;
};
```

Notice how fundamental and pointer types evaluate to `const T` and other types evaluate to `const T &`. This has been working great so far.

Now consider the following function:

```
template <class T>
void foo()
{
    typedef basic_buffer<T> _storage_type;
    typedef typename _storage_type::value_type _value_type;

    _value_type value = 0;
    _storage_type _storage;

    _storage.insert(_storage.end(), value);
}
```

Several details are omitted. This is what I get:

```
error: no matching member function for call to 'insert'
    _storage.insert(_storage.end(), value);
    ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
```

What surprises me is this overload version not being matched:

```
note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from '_value_type' (aka 'unsigned char') to 'typename argument<value_type>::type' (aka 'conditional<std::is_fundamental<unsigned
      char>::value || std::is_pointer<unsigned char>::value, const unsigned char, const unsigned char &>') for 2nd argument
    const_iterator insert(const_iterator position, typename argument<value_type>::type val)
```

To make matters even more confusing, if I cast `value` to `_value_type` (that, notably, is already its type) it works:

```
_storage.insert(_storage.end(), static_cast<_value_type>(value));
```

So I can solve this by casting `value`, but rather not. What is happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have

```
typedef std::conditional<std::is_fundamental<T>::value || std::is_pointer<T>::value, const T, const T &> type;
```

So type is a `std::conditional<std::is_fundamental<T>::value || std::is_pointer<T>::value, const T, const T &>`

When you call

```
_storage.insert(_storage.end(), value);
```

It is trying to convert `value` to a `std::conditional<std::is_fundamental<T>::value || std::is_pointer<T>::value, const T, const T &>`

You need to add `::type` to the conditional to get the resulting type from the condition.

```
typedef std::conditional<std::is_fundamental<T>::value || std::is_pointer<T>::value, const T, const T &>::type type;
```

Comment: Of course! How did I miss that :) oddly enough, now I have the same problem with `_storage.insert(_storage.end(), value | carry)`, which I didn't before, due to the bitwise operator's return type. It's funny that the compiler was capable of deducing one type and not the other, but that already makes sense solving with a cast. Thanks!

Comment: @AndréFratelli What are `value` and `carry` when you try it?

Comment: `value` and `carry` are both of `_value_type` (aka `uint8_t`), but that was not the problem. I was being misled by the previous error, because this one was telling me that the call was _ambiguous_. This is due to the fact that besides the `typename argument<value_type>::type` overload I also had a `value_type &&` overload, which is meant for class types. Apparently these two cannot coexist, which bears a problem with my `argument` design approach. For now I commented out the `&&` and it's working well, I'm thinking of reviewing this issue later. Or maybe you know how to solve? ;)

Comment: @AndréFratelli I would have to see the code but that would be a separate question.